# iOS | Always logged in at the start of every new test

Tags: ios, appium, ui-automation

Not sure was this already asked here, but I could use help with an issue. I will provide any additional info if needed.

As said in the title, I would like to not be logged in after every test has been run, since I need to go through login test first. My colleague on Android just goes through her test, and does `Driver.Quit/Dispose();` at the end, and she’s logged out for every other/next test after that.

On the other hand, for me (iOS), after I dispose of my driver - when the next test starts, I’m frequently (if not all the time) already logged in, and then I need to handle that case as well - and I’m trying to avoid it. I know that some login data is kept in the iOS keychain - and I can reproduce this issue manually with our app - if I uninstall the app, while being logged in - after I reinstall the app and start it - I’m already logged in.

Is there a way to handle this in a proper way? I’ve tried a lot of things, like actually logging out through the app, but that adds additional code, and makes it more complicated. Tried few additional capabilities - but nothing worked.

Comment: Have your post-test code delete the keychain item?

Comment: If there is some data kept in the keychain and you are still logged in even after re-installing the application, then I would suggest you ask the developers to integrate a way to clean the keychain based on app arguments. For example you could have a logic in the app to clean it when "cleanData" argument is provided to the app and then start the app through Appium using this argument.

Comment: @drunkencheetah I talked to developers yesterday, and they said it just a couple of lines of code to do this - so it's probably going to be an easy task, just need confirmation from the "higher-ups" for this. Reason I asked is to have some kind of a workaround until then - but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It sounds like your app is keeping you logged in even with terminating/reinstalling the app.  I would take a look closer and see if there's an issue attempting to log the user out when the app terminates or if there's a reason it's not coming to the login page after reinstalling.

I have code inside my iOS app that closes out the app if the app is terminated.  And the below code works for me with appium as it terminates the app which also means it logs me out.

Try this to terminate your app:

```
const bundleId = "com.yourappsbundleid"
driver.terminateApp(bundleId)
```

Also note that appium's website provides more information and also ways to do this in other languages. See: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/terminate-app/